# Deducing whether or not an element is irreducible in a given ring

Tags: ring-theory

So I have two examples for which I have to determine if the given elements are irreducible or not:

$$1+2\sqrt{-2}\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]\tag{1}$$

$$5\in \mathbb{Z}[i]\tag{2}$$

So for $(1)$, I did the following:

Suppose that $1+2\sqrt{-2} = ab$ for some $a,b \in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, and neither $a$ nor $b$ are units.

Then $N(1+2\sqrt{-2}) = 9 =3\cdot 3=N(a)N(b)$, where $N$ is the norm map.

So am I correct in thinking that $N(a)=1\implies a=1$? Is this statement true in general?

So assuming that $N(a)=1\implies a=1$, which is a unit. Applying a similar argument for $b$ we must then have $N(a)=N(b)=3$.

I then get stuck here.

For $(2)$

I tried $N(5)=25=5\cdot 5=N(a)N(b)\implies N(a)=N(b)=5$ - and again I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint for the second part: $5=1+4=1^2+2^2$

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Ah I see, so then $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$, both of which are not units and therefore $5$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Yep $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Okay thanks. Any ideas for the first one?

Comment: You can describe elements in that ring with norm 3 fairly easily. I think the easiest way would just be working with that list of elements

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Ah okay I just figured it out now, so we can write $a=u+d\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, then $N(a)=u^2+2d^2=3\implies u=\pm 1,\quad d=\pm 1$, and similar for $b$.  Then some trial and error yields $(1+2\sqrt{-2})=(1-\sqrt{-2})(-1+\sqrt{2})$ so it is not irreducible. Is this correct?